# linux how to get the deepest child folders?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

My current directory contents are:

```
$ tree
├── README.md
├── deploy.sh
├── grizzly
│   ├── configs
│   │   ├── nginx-conf.yml
│   │   └── proxy-conf.yml
│   ├── deployments
│   │   ├── api.yml
│   │   ├── celery.yml
│   │   └── proxy.yml
│   ├── secrets
│   └── services
│       ├── api.yml
│       └── proxy.yml
├── ingress.yml
└── shared
    ├── configs
    │   └── rabbitmq.yml
    └── env
        └── variables.yml
```

I plan to create a script that will run `$ kubectl apply` for all files in this tree.

My thought is to get all the child directories then just have all those child directories(expected to have the yml files) execute `$ kubectl apply` for my resources to be created.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to apply all yamls which are somewhere within the directory structure of the current directory.

Just run:

```
kubectl apply -f . --recursive
```

If you want to filter the files based on certain conditions you can use a construct like

```
find . -type f | grep 'api.yml' | xargs -n 1 kubectl apply -f
```